# I removed all empty folders in System32

Tags: windows, operating-systems, system32

Well it happens to the best of us...
I was running a batch file which runs a RD XXX for every folder in a location and accidentally run it as admin inside System32. 
It saw that it removed 3-4 empty folders. 
Should i be worried? 
Is there a command that will recreate the needed structure System32 needs?
Thank you.

Comment: Yes; Windows very likely will not boot. You will more than likely have to reinstall Windows

Comment: RD XXX ... inside System32. ....  it removed 3-4 empty folders.   <-- Does the system start?  If so, run Windows 10 Repair Install from the Microsoft Medial Creation Link and start with Keep Everything to see if that fixes your system.

Comment: enter recovery mode and restore, or open command prompt in that mode then run `sfc /scannow`

Comment: To your questions, yes computer boots normally without any issues (that i can see).

Answer (score 0):

Besides the standard Windows analysis and repair functions which are amply documented and explained elsewhere, there is no special system that checks and repairs System32 folders.

If chkdsk and the DISM commands, or System Restore and the bootable recovery tools do not work, you will need to perform a new (or repair) installation of Windows.

Comment: Computer boots up normally. I run Chkdsk and DISM commands and they did not find any issues. So i am probably fine correct?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. I'm of the strong opinion that you've broken your computer irrevocably. Whether the fault is made visible today, or in a day, a week, or a month, depends on what was deleted and when it will be required. You don't just delete things from System32 without having serious problems at some point. Do you want those problems to happen when you really, REALLY need the computer to work, or do you want to take the effort to correctly repair the problem now?